# How to remove extra array from Json data in php

Tags: php, arrays, json

I want to remove Extra array from this JSON "data". 
how to do this in PHP. Is it any function in PHP that solve it.?

```
 {
   "data": [
     [
       {
          "user_id": "654120",
          "user_name": "Jhon_Thomsona",
          "user_image": null
       }
     ],
     [
       {
          "user_id": "1065040766943114",
          "user_name": "Er Ayush_Gemini",
          "user_image": "KP8LSHQFwk.png"
       }
     ]
  ]
}
```

I want my final array to look like this:

```
 {
   "data": [
       {
          "user_id": "654120",
          "user_name": "Jhon_Thomsona",
          "user_image": null
       },
       {
          "user_id": "1065040766943114",
          "user_name": "Er Ayush_Gemini",
          "user_image": "KP8LSHQFwk.png"
       }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what mean by "extra array"? (I think I know, just not sure...)

Comment: There is no PHP function that reads your mind and removes whatever you deem unnecessary. You have to write it yourself.

Comment: I want Like this.
"data": [
  {
    "user_id": "654120",
    "user_name": "Jhon_Thomsona",
    "user_image": null
},
{
    "user_id": "1065040766943114",
    "user_name": "Er Ayush_Gemini",
    "user_image": "KP8LSHQFwk.png"
  }
]

Comment: you don't "remove from json". You never manipulate the json. You manipulate the data structure the json was created FROM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the extra array layer around each user object by mapping `reset` over the elements of `data`, then reencoding as JSON.

```
$data = json_decode($json);
$data->data = array_map('reset', $data->data);
$json = json_encode($data);
```

Of course, if you are creating this JSON yourself, you should avoid creating this structure to begin with rather than altering it after the fact.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$foo = json_decode($yourjson);
$data = [];
foreach($foo->data as $array) $data = array_merge($data, $array);
$foo->data = $data;
$yourjson = json_encode($foo);
```

**EDIT** Use of array_merge + Oriented object